# Visual Studio 2017 Copy too many files when using a .net standard library

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have two projects:

1. TestStandardLib(based on .Net Standard 2.0, to use in .Net Framework, .Net Core, Xamarin...)
2. TestMain(based on .Net Framework 4.6, just to test)

if I reference project TestStandardLib in TestMain, the compile result is 100+ files:

TestMain.exe

TestStandardLib.dll

System.Runtime.*.dll

System.Threading.*.dll

...

...

But I think I only need 2 files:

TestMain.exe and TestStandardLib.dll

because I think the .Net Framework 4.6 should have included .net standard relative dll. And I do test that if I delete the other 100+ files, remaining only TestMain.exe and TestStandardLib.dll, it works ok!

How to solve this?

Comment: What you think is far from the truth, and "it works ok" is just an illusion. Rick wrote about every possible details you need, and "LibGit2Sharp has added back a 4.6 Target" section talks about the actual solution, https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Feb/19/Using-NET-Standard-with-Full-Framework-NET

Comment: Thanks for your great help! This artical is really what I want.And now I am clear about the reason and the solution.Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Clear the output folder

Then expand references node, select the assembly, check the properties window.

Copy Local property should be False.

[image: copy-local-false]